# React Native app: cannot connect to dev server, but the simulator is running - why?

Tags: android, react-native

The image describes my current situation properly. Please have a look at it first.

[image: my current situation in image.]

I am running my app on React Native. I have Android simulator on. I give the command to start the app. The app build finishes, but it says that virtual device not found, and in my simulator, if I open the app manually, it says that it cannot connect to Development server. It shows some issues.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Try run `react-native run-android` to connect your app to the emulator

Answer (score 0):

1. Check USB Debugging is on(mostly running on virtual devices)
2. Check how you created project(react-native-cli or Expo) and run relevant app run command
3. Make sure your development server(node.js) is running when you run app. Sometimes it crashes then you have to again run command to run app

If all the step does not solve your issue try to uninstall app from device and run app again. Since react-native is still developing and its wired sometime these tricks works

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue in Ubuntu 16.04. In my case the problem was that node packager wasn't running.

To check is packager is running easily you can open the browser and enter

http://localhost:8081/

You must see "React Native packager is running."

If you dont, then you can start packager from console running

react-native start

If you get an error like

" ERROR  watch /your/project/path/android/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values-ru ENOSPC"

Then run first

echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p

Then run react-native start again and press the letter R twice in the emulator to reload.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the screenshot, seems like you don't have adb installed because there is a clear 'adb: not found error'.

Luckily Android studio ships with adb and is present in platform-tools under your Android SDK. (generally in /home/your-user-name/Android/Sdk/)

You only need to use it. Create a symbolic link in '/usr/bin/' or '/usr/local/bin/' depending how you'd like to use it.

Run the command:

> sudo ln -s ~/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb /usr/local/bin/

After this run the app.